# How can I bind media controls to my mouse?

Tags: mouse, hid, media

I recently began dual booting Kali Linux alongside Windows, and I'd like to set up media controls with my Logitech g502 Hero. Using G Hub on windows I had the scroll wheel left/right set to previous/next track and the "g9" button set to toggle pause. I downloaded Piper hopping to do the same but it doesn't support it implicitly and I couldn't find any keybindings for media controls to use. The media controls on my keyboard still work just fine so I'm hoping there is some solution to using the same on my mouse.